# R: Recode cells in matrix with no symmetric match

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an adjacency matrix of 0s and 1s that indicate tie nominations. Some nominations are not reciprocated, so the matrix is asymmetrical.

I would like to recode the cell values from 1 to 0 if they do not have a symmetrical match.

Sample small matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
```

Output desired:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the data, then a one-liner will do it. Treat `0/1` as logical and AND the matrix with its transpose. `+()` coerces to integer and the trick is done.

```r
x <- scan(text="    0    1    0    1
    0    0    1    0
    0    0    0    1
    1    0    1    0")
x <- matrix(x, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

y <- +(x & t(x))
y
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    1
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    1
#> [4,]    1    0    1    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmin` like below

```
> pmin(x,t(x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: This is the fastest so far, upvoted.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks, yours is fast as well, and upvoted already :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way for this specific case. This is slower than @ThomasIsCoding's solution, and would not work for numbers other than 1, 0. If your matrix allows an inverse, then:

```
A <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))

A_inv <- solve(A)
A_inv + t(A_inv)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but you should be aware that `solve` is expensive (especially when you have large matrix) and it works only if the matrix is non-singular.

Comment: You are right. I put this as a slower, constrained alternative. This can be improved slightly by calling `solve()` once. `A_inv <- solve(A)` and then do: `A_inv + t(A_inv)`  There are better answers above to be honest. I like the `pmin()` solution best.